# Enterprise library 5.0 logging block in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, enterprise-library

I have download the Enterprise library 5.0 in my PC from microsoft. i installed it. now i want to use only logging application block with asp.net application. ao what steps i need to follow? Or do i need to add reference of logging dll from installation location (programe files..\Enterprise Library 5.0) and directly use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look the these articles, they should answer your question.

- [Get Logging with the Enterprise Library (this is one is a bit old)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/GetLoggingWithEntLib.aspx)
- [Logging via the Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/logging-via-the-microsoft-enterprise-library/5940859)
- [How to use Logging Application Block in Enterprise Library 5.0](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1325-how-to-use-logging-application-block-in-enterprise-library-50-.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are many steps to get it working, you have to add a configuration section to your web.config, you should check the enterprise library labs found here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6932, it is a walkthroughtfor configuring each of the enterprise library components

Comment: thats what i want. i want to know atleast single way to use the logging application block. becuase ways given by microsoft is bit confusing. in the sence i simply want to use its object model.